# how to hide drop pin and map and satellite from google map

Tags: javascript, google-maps

this is my code

```
        function initMap(latitude, longitude) {
          var myLatLng = {lat: latitude, lng: longitude};

          var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
            zoom: 13,
            center: myLatLng
          });

          var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: myLatLng,
            map: map,
            title: 'Hello World!'
          });
        }
```

and here is how it's displayed

[image: http://i.imgur.com/jc0rLea.png]

I would like to hide drop pin and Map/Satellite, how would I do that?

Comment: for disabling map/satellite and other  default UI u can try  disableDefaultUI: true from here https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/controls#DisablingDefaults by pin u mean marker ?

Comment: By pin i mean the yellow little person above the arrows, will your suggestion also remove zoom + -, i want to keep them

Comment: yes that will remove all by u have option to remove those individually also

Comment: Can you show me how?

Answer (score 1):

Form here https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/controls#DisablingDefaults

Either can use

```
   disableDefaultUI: true
```

globally to remove all from UI or use

```
 {
   zoomControl: boolean,
   mapTypeControl: boolean,
   scaleControl: boolean,
   streetViewControl: boolean,
   rotateControl: boolean,
   fullscreenControl: boolean
 }
```

to remove/add individually